# How i can use pickle.dumps?

Tags: python, encryption

I have a pickle
I did encryption ( with XOR algo)
I would like to use pickle.dumps to save my encrypted pickle like an object
but it s not working
what is wrong please?

encryption

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(dict, open('dict', 'wb'))
pickle.load(open('dict', 'rb'))


from hashlib import sha256
entree = input("put file name : ")
sortie = input("put the final file: ")
key = input("put the key: ")
keys = sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()

with open(entree ,'rb') as f_entree:
    with open(sortie,'wb') as f_sortie:
        i=0
        while f_entree.peek():
            c = ord(f_entree.read(1))
            j = i % len(keys)
            b = bytes([c^keys[j]])
            f_sortie.write(b)       
            i=i+1 


#give me an encrypted file

# now i need to modify this script to save the decryption like an object using pickle.dumps after decryption  :

#for decryption : 
from hashlib import sha256
entree = input("put file name : ")
sortie = input("put the final file: ")
key = input("put the key: ")
keys = sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()

with open(entree ,'rb') as f_entree:
    with open(sortie,'wb') as f_sortie:
        i=0
        while f_entree.peek():
            c = ord(f_entree.read(1))
            j = i % len(keys)
            b = bytes([c^keys[j]])
            f_sortie.write(b)       
            i=i+1
```

Comment: Your title asks about pickle but your code does not use pickle at all. What are you really asking about?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I get the pickle data without writing it to a file?

You might use [`pickle.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) function which does

> Return the pickled representation of the object *obj* as a `bytes`
> object, instead of writing it to a file.

Answer (score -1):

In general cases when a library API doesn't have dumps() method you can use [IO module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html).
In your case you would do the following:

```
import io

<...>
with open(entree, 'rb') as f_entree:
   f_sortie = io.BytesIO()
   i=0
   while f_entree.peek():
      <...>
      f_sortie.write(b)       
      i=i+1 

print(f_sortie)
```